# Linear extensions that preserve norm of linear functional.

Tags: functional-analysis

$(a)$ Let $\mathbb{X}$ a normed space and $f \in Z^{\prime},$ where $Z$ is subspace of $\mathbb{X}.$ If $f$ have two distinct extensions $f_{1},f_{2}\in\mathbb{X}^{\prime}$ that preserve the norm of $f,$ show that $f$ have infinity linear extensions that preserve norm of $f.$

$(b)$ Consider the space $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with norm $\|(x, y)\|=\max \{|x|,|y|\} .$ In subspace $Z=\{(t, t): t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ consider the linear functional $f:Z\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(t,t)=t.$ Find two distinct linear extensions defined in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that preserve norm of $f.$

Can anybody help me? I had no idea

Comment: As a first step in (b), have you tried evaluating the norm of $f$? If not, I recommend it. If so, did you get stuck, or did you find it and just struggle with coming up with extensions? Irrespective of norm, have you thought about what the "general form" of extension of $f$ would look like (given how a basis of $Z$ can be extended to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the addition of only one vector)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a), consider convex combinations.

For (b), the norm of $f$ is 1. The obvious extensions are $f(x,y)=x$ and $f(x,y)=y$. Do these work?